# Phone calling is not working in phonegap android application

Tags: android, cordova

Hello I am developing application in phonegap and android device. I want to make a call from my application but its not working.

I am using following code for phone calling

```
window.location = 'tel://9999999999';
```

but its not working. Please anyone help me.

I have included cordova2.5.js also.

Answer (score 0):

what about changing it to `window.location.href = 'tel:9999999999';`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have tried it but this is also not working.

Comment: And if you try document.location.href = 'tel:+9999999999'; ?